# How to separate data in R based on conditions

Tags: r, analysis, organization

I would like to separate my data depending on certain conditions in R for data analysis but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have data that is already grouped together that I would like to separate based on certain conditions of that grouping. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

Original data: 
dataset:

```
trial position data
1 1 70
1 2 73
1 3 80
1 4 75
2 1 41
2 2 80
2 3 45
2 4 70
3 1 50
3 2 53
3 3 50
3 4 53
4 1 80
4 2 90
4 3 85
4 4 53
```

Desired data:

```
dataset1:
trial position data
1 1 70
1 2 73
1 3 80
1 4 75
4 1 80
4 2 90
4 3 85
4 4 53


dataset2:
trial position data
2 1 41
2 2 80
2 3 45
2 4 70
3 1 50
3 2 53
3 3 50
3 4 53
```

I would like to be able to separate my data, such that if the data in position 1 of each separate trial is above 50, then the entire trial information and data gets put into a data set and data in position 1 that is below 50 gets put into a separate data set. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split` to get a `list` output.  We create the grouping variable with `ave` by checking if the first value of 'data' is greater than 50 for each 'trial' group.

```
lst <- split(dataset,  with(dataset, ave(data, trial, FUN=function(x) x[1]<=50)))
```

If we need two datasets in the global environment, name the `list` elements and use `list2env` (not recommended)

```
names(lst) <- paste0('dataset', seq_along(lst))
lst
#$dataset1
#   trial position data
#1      1        1   70
#2      1        2   73
#3      1        3   80
#4      1        4   75
#13     4        1   80
#14     4        2   90
#15     4        3   85
#16     4        4   53

#$dataset2
#   trial position data
#5      2        1   41
#6      2        2   80
#7      2        3   45
#8      2        4   70
#9      3        1   50
#10     3        2   53
#11     3        3   50
#12     3        4   53


list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

#### Update

If there are cases where `position=1` is not found in 'dataset', the above code may not work well.  I am creating the `split` group with `dplyr` based on the condition that if position==1 exists and data is greater than 50, then we get TRUE for the whole group.

```
library(dplyr)
grp <- dataset %>%
          group_by(trial) %>% 
          transmute(ind= any(data>50 & position==1))%>%
          .$ind
split(dataset, grp) 
#   $`FALSE`
#   trial position data
#5      2        1   41
#6      2        2   80
#7      2        3   45
#8      2        4   70
#9      3        1   50
#10     3        2   53
#11     3        3   50
#12     3        4   53

#$`TRUE`
#   trial position data
#1      1        1   70
#2      1        2   73
#3      1        3   80
#4      1        4   75
#13     4        1   80
#14     4        2   90
#15     4        3   85
#16     4        4   53
```

We can rename the list elements as above and create separate datasets if needed.

Comment: This separates all the data into individual datasets by trial but that is not what I would like to do. I have added more examples of data to try to make it clearer. I would like to separate the data such that within each trial, if position 1 >50, then that is one dataset with all other trials that fit that condition and if position 1 <50, then that is another dataset with other trials that fit that condition as well.

Comment: @RHatesMe Updated the post

Comment: whats wrong with using ``sapply`` to a set of conditions for splitting. e.e ``conditions = c(50, 100); col = 2; sapply(conditions, function(x) data[data[,col]<x,])``

Comment: @nathanesau  Based on the input data, I am not getting the expected output.  Here, the condition is to check only the first element of 'data' column per each 'trial' group.  In your code, you are looping through each condition and checking all the elements of the 2nd column.

Comment: @akrun your solution is mostly working but is not correctly organizing the data and I am not sure why. There are still datapoints where data is more or less than 50 that is being categorized into the wrong dataset. I will provide any other information you need.

Comment: @RHatesMe  Based on the data you provided, I am getting the same result as the expected one.

Comment: @RHatesMe I have to go now.  If you can update with another input data (preferably using `dput`) that gives the wrong result, I will take a look later.

Comment: I realized that the code is separating the data such that all instances where position=2 is being put into a separate dataset, regardless of if value in data is greater than or less than 50 or not. I also may be complicating things a bit but there is another layer of the code where there is subject information that may be influencing the code's ability to function or not.

Comment: @RHatesMe If you look at my code, I used the condition with only the first value of 'data' (`x[1]<=50`) for each 'trial'.  So, I don't understand how it is separating the data based on `position =2`.  Do you have cases where there are missing `position=1` for trial group?  If that is the case, how do you want to deal with those?

Comment: @RHatesMe I updated the post by including the `position==1` criteria.  Hopefully, it will work.  In your original dataset, it may be also the case that the columns were not ordered so that position =1 may not be the first observation per each trial group.